# Bug: Null pointer deference of String

Tags: java, string, nullpointerexception

The test code below leads to a "null pointer deference" bug on a String Array(on line 6). This leads to a NullPointerException.

```
public class TestString {
public static void main (String args[]) {
String test [] = null;
for (int i =0; i < 5; i++) {
  String testName = "sony" + i;
  test [k] = testName;
}
}
}
```

-- How do I fix this?
-- What is it that causes this bug?

Thanks,
Sony

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to initialize your array like this, before :

```
test = new String[5];
```

Whenever you use an array, the JVM need to know it exists and its size.

In java there are many way to initialize arrays.

```
test = new String[5];
```

Just create an array with five emplacements. (You can't add a sixth element)

```
test = new String[]{"1", "2"};
```

Create an array with two emplacements and which contains the values 1 and 2.

```
String[] test = {"1", "2"};
```

Create an array with two emplacements and which contains the values 1 and 2. But as you noticed it must be donne at the same time with array *declaration*.

In Java arrays are *static*, you specify a size when you create it, and you can't ever change it.

Answer (score 3):

There are too many errors in your code.
1) What is k?
2) You need to initialize the test array first.

```
String test[] = new String[5]; // or any other number
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not initializing your array. On the third row you set it to null and then on the sixth row you're trying to set a string to an array that does not exists. You can initialize the array like this:

```
String test [] = new String[5];
```

Answer (score 0):

Change  `String test[] = null;` to  `String test[] = new String[5];` 
an array must be initialized.

See: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html